# Хранение и показ справочников в системе

Tags: spring, mvc, java, jsp

День добрый, граждане!

Мне было бы очень интересно узнать, как вы решаете совершенно классическую задачу про хранение справочников в системе, которая использует `Spring MVC 3` + `JSP` в качестве `view`.

А именно:

(1, простой случай): есть некий набор строк, которые надо хранить, показывать и как-то использовать.
Пример: обычный справочник городов.

(2, сложный случай): есть некий набор сущностей, в каждой из которых есть поля, которые используются сходным образом; то есть это не просто справочник, но и сущность, которая будет использоваться в бизнес-логике.
Пример: класс, содержащий настройки внешнего веб-сервиса: адрес, пароли, названия аттрибутов и т.д. Таких сервисов много, пользователь выбирает что использовать.

**Как организовать показ и хранение этого в системе?**

Я вижу такие варианты:

**1) ENUM**
+ удобно показывать в JSP:

```
<form:select path="webservice">                                                 
<c:forEach items="${enumList}" var="enum">
<form:option value="${enum.name}"><spring:message code="${enum.label}"/>    </form:option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

`-` по сути hardcoded

**2) Хранить все в таблице и считывать.** 
 + легко менять через интерфейс
 - непонятно, как показывать в `JSP`. Откуда взять имена ресурсов для использования в качестве названий опций в селектах? Разве что занести в таблицу названия spring-ресурсов, но это странно выглядит.

**3) Объединение:** считать такие сущности из базы и инжектировать их в `ENUM`. Не слишком ли?

Где идеальный вариант?

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите загрузить все справочники в объекты классов, а затем как-то использовать их? (это для второго варианта)

Comment: Да, так и есть. Но я не знаю, как красиво подцепить к ним подписи для интерфейса (то, что обычно цепляется через `<spring:message code="myparam.name"/>`). Не пихать же эти `myparam.name` в таблицу. Хотя с другой стороны чем это хуже hardcoded названий параметров.

Comment: А интересно, каким образом можно инжектировать данные базы в ENUM?

Comment: Ну у енума могут быть поля, в них можно что-то занести. Но не будет ли это уродством я не уверен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обратиться к старым добрым принципам ООП, и мыслить и действовать объектами. Т.е. для каждой определенной задачи свой объект, который отвечает только сам за себя.
Для одной задачи один объект, для второй задачи - второй. Это дает преимущество в том, что если заказчик в очередной раз захочет вас задолбать и изменить некую функциональность, это получится легче и безопаснее. Хранение, мне кажется, не надо делать в системе. На то она и база данных, что хранит данные и выдает их когда надо. Там же, в БД, построена вся система на максимально быстрый и производительный поиск/вставку.

Добавить можно еще краткий пример. Вот, у вас есть несколько таблиц. И надо сделать из них выборку и данные, красивые и без всего лишнего отправить не `jsp`. Решение:
создаете объект `некотораяВыборка`, в котором все это создается и методом `getData()`, возвращается готовое для отправки на страницу (или в `Spring`, и потом на страницу) сообщение.

Что касается `spring:message` (некоторые сообщения на странице, элементы интерфейса, как я понимаю), то я думаю что не надо сохранять эти пояснения/сообщения в базу данных. Это касается только интерфейсной части, и она должна быть с интерфейсной частью, а не с программным `Java`-кодом. Т.е. я хочу сказать если вы, программист отправите это в БД, и как-то программно будете извлекать все эти сообщения то, когда придет *дизайнер*, он ничего не сделает с вашими `message`. А так хоть легко залезет в файл `.properties`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Антон! Вот что мне не нравится в такой схеме: допустим есть некий list box куда я заношу options из справочника. Если не хранить spring:message в базе то я не смогу легко добавить элементы в этот list box. По сути мне придется хардкодить: если так, то показать этот message, иначе другой. Это конечно не очень хорошо. 
Чтобы обойти можно разве что хранить коды messages в базе или в енуме.

Comment: Ну, если так много разных сообщений, которые будут выводиться в виде списка то, может, и хорошо занести в БД. Но в `ENUM`, на сколько я знаю, нельзя динамически поля вносить. Если можно, то я очень удивлюсь и попрошу показать как это делать.  
В принципе, есть примеры, когда в БД хранят целые HTML-странички (напр. `DLE`, движок на `PHP`).